# How to display list of nodes in responsive grid?

Tags: 7, theming

What module should I use to implement this?

Each item has photo, taxonomy, title, description. And it has a horizontal mouse hover movement. Could you kindly recommend drupal modules to implement this grid?

Comment: Implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided is listed on "do not" list [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I edited it for you to make it more answerable. You can, of course, rollback if you disagree with my edit.

Comment: you can do it with any kind of grid, thing you have to do is styling(css)

Comment: @Bala there is more to it than css. See my answer and project page of module linked.

Answer (score 4):

[Views Responsive Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid) provide basics of functionality you need:

> Views Responsive Grid provides a views plugin for displaying content in a responsive(mobile friendly) grid layout. Rather than trying to force the standard Views grid display to work for mobile this provides the same functionality, but in DIVs instead of tables. Provided is also the ability to specify a horizontal or vertical grid layout which will properly stack the content on a mobile display.

The rest is fine tuning and theming.

Comment: @argenhong I got as low as -6 on my first question or two, so yea, don't feel discouraged. Just read help center and ask again when you have something allowed here to ask :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Views Fluid Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fluid_grid) module, it offers the option to add separate css classes. If this grid doesn't fit your requirements then check the other option in @Molot comment.

> The plugin settings form provides options to define the width and
>   height of the elements in the grid. But it also provides advanced
>   layout options implemented in separate CSS classes that allow you to
>   define item margins, alignment and a couple of CSS3 properties
>   (box-shadow and border-radius).

Comment: Hello. Bala. I appretiate about your answer. ^^